# Cannot upload audio data (audio/mpeg-3 gets rejected)

Tags: deno, oak

I'm trying to send a microphone recording from JS (as a Blob in FormData) to Deno/Oak, but I get this error:

```
BadRequestError - The form contained 
  content type "audio/mpeg-3" 
  which is not supported by the server.
```

Here is my Oak endpoint:

```
const body = await context.request.body({ type: 'form-data' })   
// next line triggers the above error
const data = await body.value.read()
```

My setup is this:

```
app.use(oakCors())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())
app.use(router.routes())
await app.listen({ port: PORT })
```

How can I allow Oak to accept `"audio/mpeg-3"` as a data type?

Comment: "audio/mpeg-3" is not a valid RCF mimetype. How are you sending data (and declaring this type?). Use "audio/mpeg" instead

Comment: Thanks so much @EdoardoLobbiani! I had the the type incorrectly in JS:
new Blob(this.audioChunks, { type: 'audio/mpeg-3' })

If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably in the client when declaring mimetype: "audio/mpeg-3" is not valid.
Use "audio/mpeg" instead as described in [RCF documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003.html)